# AWS cognito machine-to-machine oauth

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have an API which large number of devices connect to. These devices are distributed by us and can be considered as trusted. They do not have a built-in Web browser.

I'm considering to use OAuth `Client Credentials` flow (flow for machine-to-machine communication). However, I wonder if Cognito `Client Credentials` flow is not designed for this purpose as it allows only 25 App Clients.

Is there another OAuth flow (within Cognito) that can be used in this case?

I suppose `Resource Owner Password Grant` can be used here but can't figure out how to enable it in Cognito.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use one Cognito client for one device? Each client is supposed to represent a type of sign in mechanism. If all of the devices are supposed to sign in in the same manner, then one client is sufficient.

Comment: The reason is to identify and distinguish each client. If the same client id/secret is used for all devices doesn't it invalidate the whole idea of authentication?

Comment: But each client i.e. device will have a a unique account associated in the userpool. And you need to mention the callback URLs of all of these devices in the App client settings (comma separated) and then it will work.